# How to create method without effecting each others?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, flutter-layout

I created a method that named "Button". This method changes container's color and I want to use this method two times but I don't want "Button" method to not effect other methods. I don't know how to do it. Finally i want to create a method and use it several times but i don't want them to effect each others.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Button(color1!),
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Button(color1!),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color? color1 = Colors.green;

  FlatButton Button(Color color) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          color1 = Colors.blue;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        color: color1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include what do you mean by `other methods. ` it would be easy if you provide some example code on it

Comment: You should create a specific widget rendering the FlatButton, the widget will be responsible of the color.
The probleme here is that you use the same variable ('color1') for the two buttons.

Comment: I mean i want to use same method several times and i want change container’s color on a condition but it effects all methods because they are same methods. So i dont want to create each time, i want to use same method again and again

Comment: The method is not the problem, the variable is.
Use a specific variable for each button or create a specific widget to build the button

Comment: Okay i got it i should create a specific widget but does not it effect each other again?